# React Native SectionList Performance Issue: Extremely Low JS Frame Rate While Scrolling React Native SectionList

Tags: react-native, performance, react-native-sectionlist

Scrolling a SectionList results in unreasonably low JS frame rate dips (~30) for simple cell renders (a single text label) and gets much worse if cell contents are any more complex (several text labels in each cell will result in single digit JS frame rate dips).

The user facing-problem manifested by the low JS frame rate is very slow response times when a user taps anything after scrolling (it can be ~5 seconds delay).

[Here's an example repo which creates both a FlatList and a SectionList each with 10,000 items on a single screen (split laterally across the middle of the screen). It's a managed Expo app (for ease of reproduction) and it's written in Typescript (because I'm used to that). The readme describes setup steps if you need them. Run the app on a physical device and turn on React Native's performance monitor to view the JS frame rate. Then scroll each of the lists as fast as you can to view the differing effects on the JS frame rate while scrolling a FlatList vs a SectionList.](https://github.com/pachun/list-performance)

Here's the entire source (from that repo's App.tsx file; 61 lines) if you prefer to bootstrap it yourself, or eyeball it here without going to GitHub:

```js
import React from "react"
import { FlatList, SectionList, Text, View } from "react-native"

const listSize = 10_000
const listItems: string[] = Array.from(
  Array(listSize).keys(),
).map((key: number) => key.toString())

const alwaysMemoize = () => true
const ListItem = React.memo(
  ({ title }: { title: string }) => (
    <View style={{ height: 80 }}>
      <Text style={{ width: "100%", textAlign: "center" }}>{title}</Text>
    </View>
  ),
  alwaysMemoize,
)

const flatListColor = "green"
const flatListItems = listItems

const sectionListColor = "blue"
const sectionListItems = listItems.map(listItem => ({
  title: listItem,
  data: [listItem],
}))

const approximateStatusBarHeight = 40

const App = () => {
  const renderItem = React.useCallback(
    ({ item }: { item: string }) => <ListItem title={item} />,
    [],
  )
  const renderSectionHeader = React.useCallback(
    ({ section: { title } }: { section: { title: string } }) => (
      <ListItem title={title + " section header"} />
    ),
    [],
  )

  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, paddingTop: approximateStatusBarHeight }}>
      <FlatList
        style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: flatListColor }}
        data={flatListItems}
        renderItem={renderItem}
        keyExtractor={item => item}
      />
      <SectionList
        style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: sectionListColor }}
        sections={sectionListItems}
        renderItem={renderItem}
        renderSectionHeader={renderSectionHeader}
        keyExtractor={item => item}
      />
    </View>
  )
}

export default App
```

[image: FlatList JS Frame Rate Performance]

[image: SectionList JS Frame Rate Performance]

Have I missed some performance optimization/am I doing something wrong? Or is this React Native's expected performance?

Another question as a side note: If I don't set the height of each of the cells to something reasonably tall (eg 80 in the example above) and just let the height adjust to the height of the contained text (14pt I believe), the JS frame rate dip for both types of lists becomes quite bad; 20 JS frames or less.

I'll also note here that the performance tests shown in the screen shots were done on an iPhone 13 mini.

Comment: have you found a solution? I have the same problem